# Transform Controls Bug in Photoshop CC 2019 Update

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Found a little bug in the most recent Photoshop CC 2019 update that makes the **Transform Tool** controls invisible in the workspace. The controls are still functional but you have to find the controls by guessing the location of the nodes and keeping a close watch on the cursor for when the correct action is activated. Ticking the `Show Transform Controls` option in the toolbar doesn’t bring them back either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution:

Navigate to **Photoshop > Preferences > General > Reset Preferences on Quit**

**Restart Photoshop** and the controls will return to normal.

Answer (score 0):

The bounding box will return if you go to Preferences > General > Use Legacy Free Transform.